# sql count function used for employee salary

Tags: sql

sql count the salary + and - value..example 1000 and -1000 as same for count..in count value = 2

```
insert into salary1 values ('melvin','15000')
insert into salary1 values ('suresh','15000')
insert into salary1 values ('melvin','-15000') 
insert into salary1 values ('suresh','-15000')
```

........ count salary in display value in 4 not 2 and 2........

Comment: You need to supply a lot more information than just  dropping some "hints". As it is your question will be closed as "unclear what you are asking". Please **[edit]** your question (do **not** put it into a comment) and add some sample data preferably in [table form](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, welcome to SO.  As others have said, please try to be more specific in asking questions.  We understand that english is not the first language of most people, so do not be shy!  When asking questions to do with sql, it also helps if you specify which database you are using, as features differ between the various providers.

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
declare @employees table
(firstname varchar(20),
lastname varchar(20),
salary decimal (18,2))

INSERT INTO @employees VALUES
('Donald','Duck', 1000.10), 
('Mickey','Mouse', -1000.10),
('Daffy','Duck', 1000.10), 
('Minny','Mouse', 9999.99)

SELECT ABS(salary), COUNT(ABS(salary)) cnt 
FROM @employees
GROUP BY ABS(salary)
```

This gives results of 1000.10 3 and 9999.99 1

To ignore the sign of a value, use ABS as I have shown.  Also it helps, if you provide sample data in similar form to that used in my answer, i.e. code that someone can copy and paste.  It saves everyone time, and remember people are giving their time for free here!

HTH

Comment: insert into salary1 values ('melvin','15000') insert into salary1 values ('suresh','15000') insert into salary1 values ('melvin','-15000') insert into salary1 values ('suresh','-15000') ........ count values in display value in 4 not 2 and 2..

Comment: @TamilAll.  Yes this is what my answer gives you if you replace my values with yours.  Have you tried it?

Comment: tnk u very much